# How to poll file using filename Date in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have list of text files have date in filename, like A_2016_12_30 etc. I require to poll file sorted by only date.

Please see below is the list of files.

[image]

I have tried below parameters with file component.

1. It works fine for sorting file using file timestamp.

   ```
   file://<some location>?sortBy=file:modified
   ```
2. It doesnt work based on file name. Faceing problem here.

   file://?sortBy=date:file:YYYY-MM-DD

Is there another way to do this sorting by file date using regex or something?

Below are some useful links:

1. http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html
2. http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own file sorting logic in Java, and configure it using the `sorter` option.

The built-in sort by options are for normal sorting use-cases. You have a special need, and then must write a bit of code to do this kind of sorting.

Answer (score 4):

It is example of sorting logic that Claus said.

```
package com.example;
import java.util.Comparator;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile;

public class DateFileSorter<T> implements Comparator<GenericFile<T>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(GenericFile<T> f1, GenericFile<T> f2) {
        String fileDate1 = getDateFromFilename(f1.getFileName());
        String fileDate2 = getDateFromFilename(f2.getFileName());
        return fileDate1.compareTo(fileDate2);
    }

    /**
     * Return date from file name between "_" and "."
     */
    private String getDateFromFilename(String fileName) {
        return fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("_") + 1, fileName.indexOf("."));
    }
}
```

Than add this line to your beans.xml file and sorter=#fileSorter to File endpoint.

```
<bean id="fileSorter" class="com.example.DateFileSorter"/>
```

Your files order after read.

```
: C_2016-01-14.xml
: A_2016-01-15.xml
: C_2016-06-01.xml
: A_2016-06-02.xml
: C_2016-06-02.xml
: A_2016-06-03.xml
: C_2016-06-03.xml
: A_2016-06-04.xml
: C_2016-12-29.xml
: A_2016-12-30.xml
```